# React wait for function to finish?

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to create a form where I type some data (barcode and name) and if an object with this data exists in my Products table I set states and save it in another Stocks table. But I have a problem when an objects doesn't exist. First I want to post it to a Products table and then to a target table. When I set product_id it is only visible in my saveProduct function and object is added to Stocks with id one down.
I tried also setting id in saveStocks() but it doesn't work because it is called before Products table is updated.
How to wait for it to finish? Or how to set id properly?

```
const saveProducts = () => {
    var data = {
      barcode: barcode,
      name: name,
    };

    axiosInstance.post('/products/', data)
      .then(response => {
        setBarcode(response.data.barcode);
        setName(response.data.name);
        setProductId(response.data.product_id) //doesn't update in second function

      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
  
  const saveStock = () => {
    const temp = products.filter(product => product.barcode == barcode)
    if (!temp.length) {
      saveProducts()
      getProducts()
      setProductId(products[products.length-1].product_id) //called before saveProducts()
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      var data = {
        stock_id: stock_id,
        product_id: product_id,
        count: count,
      };
      axiosInstance.post('/stocks/', data)
        .then(response => {
          setStockId(response.data.stock_id);
          setProductId(response.data.product_id);
          setCount(response.data.count);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }, 2000)
  }
```

I call saveStock() when clicking the button under my form:

```
<button className="btn btn-success" type="button" onClick={saveStock}>Add</button>
```

Comment: Can you put the code which uses `saveProducts` and `saveStock` functions to be executed. It's not clearly evident what goes wrong here without seeing where it's executed. Can you please put that as well.

Comment: @KavinduVIndika I added the line where I call saveStock and saveProducts is called inside  saveStock

Comment: So basically you want to wait till `saveProducts` to be finished before clicking on **Add** button which triggers `saveStock` function ?

Comment: @KavinduVIndika yes, I think that's the point

Comment: Why can't you have a separate button disable state which needs to be disabled untill `saveProducts` post response is back. Then you can enable it to use **Add** button. Then again, once you execute `saveStock` successfully, you can disable it again which disable the **Add** button.

Comment: @KavinduVIndika this is probably the best solution for me, thank you!

Comment: nice, I updated it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you have a separate button disable state which needs to be disabled untill `saveProducts` post response is back. Then you can enable it to use **Add** button. Then again, once you execute `saveStock` successfully, you can disable it again which disable the **Add** button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a variable that you can await and then reference before running your second API call. For example:

```
let products = await saveProducts();

if (products) {
  saveStock();
}
```

Comment: You know that it does return a promise before resolved it right ? So is there any use of having conditional statement as above ?

Comment: As you pointed out above, he did not share the code for `saveProducts` and `saveStock`, but I do know that his calls aren't properly awaiting, so he must have a call that isn't dependent on the promise. The pattern I have here is just a very clear method I use to make sure things go in order.